# Can't access non-default handler in actionbean?

Tags: java, servlets, stripes

Every time I try to call a method in my actionbean the default handler gets called and not the method.

Does anyone know what could be going wrong? Someone else has written another actionbean which can receive calls to the non-default handler and I can't see any differences between their class and mine, do I need to register it with stripes or so?

Comment: Are the ActionBeans located in the same class package?  Can you provide a some of your code as an example along with the URL you using that doesn't work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing the event parameter as part of the request?

http://test.org/MyActionBean.action
 - default handler

http://test.org/MyActionBean.action?view=
 - view event